# Reusing iPhone Views in iPad

Tags: ios

When creating a Universal application using Storyboard do people reuse the iPhone views (UITableView) etc in their iPad application or do they make all the views for the iPad from scratch? OR it depends :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends. As much as possible I like to try to reuse views but for the purpose of cusomization it usually works out where its required to make separate .xib's for ipad. If you are doing a navigation based app and you use a splitview controller you can basically reuse all of the navigation screens between iphone and iPad

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is nothing to reuse really. The layout of UITableView in matter of dimentions so different on iPad that on iPhone.

When you port your app from iPhone to iPad, you should focus for adapting the user experience for bigger screen. Not just using the same views form iPhone on iPad.